# Modal 3 main problems

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, modal-dialog

I am new to web development, I am facing some problems with the multiples modals that I have:

1. how to: prevent the background scroll while the modal is open..
2. how to: when press esc close the modal..
3. how to: when closing and reopen same modal, styles should go back to normal without refreshing the page..
   I am not using a jQuery or Bootstrap modals..

here is the javascript code that I am using:

```
var btn1 = document.getElementById("myBtncourse1");
var btn2 = document.getElementById("myBtncourse2");
var btn3 = document.getElementById("myBtncourse3");
var btn4 = document.getElementById("myBtncourse4");
var btn5 = document.getElementById("myBtncourse5");
var btn6 = document.getElementById("myBtncourse6");

var modal1 = document.getElementById('myModalcourse1');
var modal2 = document.getElementById('myModalcourse2');
var modal3 = document.getElementById('myModalcourse3');
var modal4 = document.getElementById('myModalcourse4');
var modal5 = document.getElementById('myModalcourse5');
var modal6 = document.getElementById('myModalcourse6');

btn1.onclick = function() {
modal1.style.display = "block";}
btn2.onclick = function() {
modal2.style.display = "block";}
btn3.onclick = function() {
modal3.style.display = "block";}
btn4.onclick = function() {
modal4.style.display = "block";}
btn5.onclick = function() {
modal5.style.display = "block";}
btn6.onclick = function() {
modal6.style.display = "block";}

var button1 = document.getElementById("close1");
button1.onclick = function() {
modal1.style.display = "none";}

var button2 = document.getElementById("close2");
button2.onclick = function() {
modal2.style.display = "none";}

var button3 = document.getElementById("close3");
button3.onclick = function() {
modal3.style.display = "none";}

var button4 = document.getElementById("close4");
button4.onclick = function() {
modal4.style.display = "none";}

var button5 = document.getElementById("close5");
button5.onclick = function() {
modal5.style.display = "none";}

var button6 = document.getElementById("close6");
button6.onclick = function() {
modal6.style.display = "none";}

window.onclick = function(event) {
if (event.target == modal1) {
    modal1.style.display = "none";}

if (event.target == modal2) {
    modal2.style.display = "none";}

if (event.target == modal3) {
    modal3.style.display = "none";}

if (event.target == modal4) {
    modal4.style.display = "none";}

if (event.target == modal5) {
    modal5.style.display = "none";}

if (event.target == modal6) {
    modal6.style.display = "none";} }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend you just to use bootstrap 4 modals

```
<head>
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<!-- jQuery library -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Popper JS -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js"></script>

<!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">
  Open modal
</button>

<!-- The Modal -->
<div class="modal" id="myModal">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">

      <!-- Modal Header -->
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Heading</h4>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
      </div>

      <!-- Modal body -->
      <div class="modal-body">
        Modal body..
      </div>

      <!-- Modal footer -->
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: It does fix the issuse

Answer (score 0):

For Question 2, you can try something like this in pure Javascript

```
document.addEventListener('keydown', function(event) {
    const key = event.key;
    if (key === "Escape") {
        // Do something
    }
});
```

To solve your 1st and 3rd questions, using Bootstrap framework will be more effective. As there are many predefined events and styles you can tweak in, to solve your problems.

For the models you can target the modal by class (getElementsByClassName), not by id (getElementById) as there are several models in your case.

Hope this will help you :)

Comment: thanks for the solution, it worked 100%
the problem is, I almost finished 95% of the project, I can not shift all the competed works to Bootstrap, still I am searching for a solution for the 1st and 3rd problems..

Comment: maybe you can post one of the modal's code. So that I can help

Comment: I figured it out, I had to make a simple solution: 
in the css, I added: 
    .stop-scrolling
    {
    height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    }

in the javascript I added:
    btn1.onclick = function() { //call the modal
    modal1.style.display = "block"; // show the modal
    $('body').addClass('stop-scrolling') //disable the body scroll

Comment: Great. Maybe you can put an up vote if you find the answer useful :-)